# parsing properties file in Python

Tags: python, parsing

test1.properties has entry key1=200 and test2.properties has entry key2=500

```
files = ['test1.properties', test2.properties']

for file in files:
  with open(file) as stream:
     stream = StringIO("[top]\n" + stream.read())
     parser.readfp(stream)
     print parser.items('top')
```

[('key1', '200'), ('key2', '500')]

Want to add another item in the existing list of tuples based on the file during the iteration. file1 item should be added to only test1.properties tuples and file2 item should be added to only test2.properties tuples.

[('key1', '200', 'file1'), ('key2', '500', 'file2')]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

```
import re
files = ['test1.properties', 'test2.properties']
values = []
for file in files:
  with open(file) as file_obj:
     stream = StringIO("[top]\n" + file_obj.read())
     parser.readfp(stream)
     n = re.search('(\d+)', file_obj.name).group(1)
     values.append(parser.items('top') + ('file%s' % n,))

print(values)
```

Comment: from StringIO import StringIO                                                                  n = re.search('(\d+)', stream.name).group(1)
AttributeError: StringIO instance has no attribute 'name'                                 
                                                                                                                It is Python 2.x

Comment: @spiderman You are overriding `stream` file pointer with a `StringIO` instance. change any name and then use `file_pointer.name`. I have updated code to fix that